# an MySQL INSERT error in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

This is a weird error that i didn't how to fix, I'm trying to copy a column from one table into another using the INSERT INTO statment, but phpmyadmin gives me this error: "#1054 - Champ 'student_id' inconnu dans where clause" whenever i try. According to google translate it means that my WHERE clause is invalid. But that isn't true because i double checked it and i even used other values but i still get this error.
This is the query that i'm trying to excute:

```
INSERT INTO students (parents_id) 
SELECT parent_id 
FROM parents 
where student_id=1000;
```

man this error is depressing me. tell me if you guys need to see the two tables too.

**Edit:**
This is my table structure

[image]

Comment: According to your query you should have column student_id in parents table. Do you have this column there?

Comment: No, i have it in the students table.

Comment: Okay actually you want to update parents_id column of students table, where student_id = 1000, by selecting its value from parents table? Right?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what i want.

Comment: When student is already exist with id 1000 then why you are again inserting another user [actually only parents_id] I think you should update parents_id of already present user not to insert another one. Secondly there can be alot of parents records in parent table. There must be some criteria to select correct parents_id.

Comment: Can you post your `students` and `parents` table schemas with a single row example of each?

Comment: here they are both in one picture: http://i.imgur.com/t8RkH4O.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO students (parents_id) 
(
   SELECT parent_id 
   FROM parents 
   where student_id=1000
)
```

Comment: I also recommend naming your columns consistently.  If it's parent_id in one table, and parent**s**_id in the other it can get confusing and can prevent you from using some nifty shorthand like `USING`